# Paging сохранение скрола

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, view, paging

При пересоздание View фрагмента сбрасывается скролл RecyclerView, Что приводит к тому, что при возращении на этот фрагмент, скролл после наполнения элементами заново становится в состояние 0

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334

Comment: Почти, если я сохранил в проскролил 1000 элементов, и остановился на 998, то при переходе на другой фрагмент, и возврате на старый , я хочу снова видеть 998 элемент, но увижу 1 так как из-за пагинации он загрузит 20 элементов сразу